# Launch an instance from a non-glance image in OpenStack

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, cinder

I have VM images stored locally on my system. Is there any way I could launch the instances without uploading them to glance or using them as Cinder volumes ?

Answer (score 0):

- **First**, you must check type of existing VM image, you can use `qemu-img info {image_path}` for that purpose, and then create cinder volume with size of RAW image (qemu-img info show it).
- **Second**, if image type has RAW type, run:

`dd if={image_path} of={volume_path-volume_id}`,

if image has other format do:

```
qemu-img convert -O raw {image_path} {volume_path-volume_id}.
```

- **Third**, you must set bootable flag for this volume (with command-line or horizon).
- **Fourthly**, boot instance from this volume.

`{image_path}` - is path to VM image on file system, like:
`/tmp/images/my-vm-image.iso`
`{volume_path-volume_id}` - is path to cinder volume on file system, like:
`/dev/mapper/data-volume--blabla--cinder--volume--id` for LVM or `/mnt/nfs/volume-blabla-cinder-volume-id` for NFS.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I did. However, I do not want to "dd" to the volume. Is there any way  could tweak the cinder/nova code so directly pick up the images located locally ?